# What is an English equivalent for a Russian word "скинь"?

Tags: slang

Russians have a slang word "скинуть", which means:
- send a message
- send something via e-mail
- download something on computer or a disk
- copy data from the computer to the USB stick 
and all related meaning of "sending" and "copying" in computer sphere. 
We use this word when we want to get some data as soon as possible.
Example of word by word translation: "скинь мне фото" = throw me photoes

Please, help me find an English slang equivalent.

Comment: While the answer about "shooting a file" is correct, I don't think it is nearly as widely used as "sending a file", even in informal contexts. Though admittedly, not too many people would send a file nowadays anyway! They are much more likely to *share* it online somewhere (e.g. Dropbox, Imgur, and so forth) so you could download it.

Comment: I don't think there is such a word in common usage.

Comment: Speaking as a long-time computer guy, that set of functions doesn't really fit in a single category, other than that they all involve the *transfer* of data.

Comment: try at http://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *Pop.*  For example, "Pop those files over to the boss, will you?"  It's not very common but I think people would understand you in the right context.  The good thing about "pop"  is that it's quick.  The word "over" is optional.

Comment: @aparente001 - "Pop" isn't particularly idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***shoot***:

> 6. d. *Slang* To give, send, or hand quickly: *Shoot me that stapler*.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shoot)

> **Shoot me**
>   To give me or to send me.
>   *Hey bruh, can you shoot me some bread?*

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shoot%20me

Usage examples:

> She leaned back, tried to look casual. “Look, I'm kind of pressed
>   right now, but can you shoot me some data here?” “Of what kind?” “Your
>   properties in New York?”

[Loyalty in Death](https://books.google.com/books?id=2WF5kJax0P4C&pg=PT91&dq=%22shoot%20me%20some%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT2Jagu6LSAhVsJMAKHSW8CjEQ6AEIMDAE)

> Eh, could you maybe shoot me some advice?

[www.giantbomb.com](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/off-topic-31/eh-could-you-maybe-shoot-me-some-advice-550359/)

> Anyone want to shoot me some of their favorite tech under $50 on
>   Amazon? Dug trying out your recommendations!

https://twitter.com/tldtoday/status/790063355906056192

---

Note that this is not limited to computer traffic.